# mysql DATE datatype not takeing the correct value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i have created a table ..here is the code

```
create table ddate(
ddate date);
```

after that i was trying to insert value like this

```
insert into ddate(ddate)value(2010-04-12);
```

But it is giving me a warning

> insert into ddate(ddate)value(2010-04-12) 1 row(s) affected, 1
>   warning(s): 1264 Out of range value for column 'ddate' at row 1   0.001
>   sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date literals are enclosed in single quotes, like a string literal.

```
insert into ddate(ddate)value('2010-04-12')
                              ^          ^
```

---

Without the single quotes around the literal, MySQL is evaluating that as a numeric value, the result of a calculation:

```
2010 - 04 - 12
```

Which makes the original statement essentially equivalent to

```
insert into ddate(ddate)value( 1994 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use single quotes for the date literal:

```
insert into ddate(ddate) values ('2010-04-12');
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b2a5/1)